# Accidentally pressed Remove Display from Desktop // Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I connected my laptop to an external monitor and then accidentally pressed the "Remove Display from Desktop" option in the Advanced Display Setting on Windows 10. Unfortunately, the external monitor was faulty and had no display.

Now I don't see anything on my laptop and since the external monitor is faulty, I don't see anything on that well. How do I fix it?

[image: Remove Display - Screenshot]

Comment: Disconnect the external monitor. Then restart. Press Ctrl Alt Delete, wait a few seconds and press Ctrl Alt Delete to restart. It should restart to your laptop screen.

Comment: It didn’t do anything. FYI - I don’t see anything but the hp logo and wheel when I turn on my laptop.

Comment: Get a temporary working external monitor and hook that up. Restart again.

Comment: Yeah, I just bought a new monitor. Working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer and trust you will acknowledge it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disconnect the external monitor that is not working.

Connect a new temporary monitor.

Then restart. Press Ctrl Alt Delete, wait a few seconds and press Ctrl Alt Delete to restart.

This should restart and allow you to manage the computer.